# How to use 2 different projects of Firebase Realtime Database inside the same Python script?

Tags: python, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

As shown in the official tutorial, a Firebase Realtime Database is initialized like:

```
    cred_object = firebase_admin.credentials.Certificate("key.json")
default_app = firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred_object, {
    'databaseURL':"database_url"
    })
```

after doing this, the `firebase_admin.db` method returns the initialized database.

Now I need to have 2 different projects with 2 different urls inside the same python script but couldn't understand nor found anyway to achieve this. As an example, I would like to call the second database with `firebase_admin.db2`.

I would like to know if anyone did this before or knows how to do it. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by using the nonofficial Rest API Interface of the Firebase service together with the official one.

The package I used: https://pypi.org/project/firebase/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).